# Tableau for live data analysis and migration from one DB to another(or same) on a live cycle

Tags: sql, powerbi, tableau-api, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

I just wanted to know if there is any possibility to fetch the DataBase (any DB) data and analyze it on Tableau (automated process) and dump that data to another DataBase (or SAME Database but different table) all of this should be a live operation/cycle or continuous operation/cycle.

Breakdown : Get the data from one DB and analyze it on Tableau and dump it on some other DB or the same one maybe in some different table.

All of this is to be done LIVE and maybe have a timestamp of 5 minutes.

Tried : I have already done this using PowerBI but it does not allow me to display the data analyzed from my own UI but rather I had to embed the PowerBI to my dashboard and it looks ugly

Comment: Tableau only reads data, does not write to anything. You'll need more than just tableau to accomplish your scenario.